# Horizontaly flipped/mirrored image using gdalwarp

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, raster-conversion

I am trying to mask a raster using gdal_calc (and gdalmerge). To do so, I first bring them to the same extent and resolution using gdalwarp. However, whatever I do, my raster is flipped horizontally.

```
gdalwarp inout.tif output.tif -te -180 84 180 16 -ts 86400 16320
Warning 1: -ts values have miny >= maxy. This will result in a vertically flipped image.
```

Gdalinfo gives me the following:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: input.tif
Size is 40321, 20161
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-180.004464285000012,90.004464284999997)
Pixel Size = (0.008928570000000,-0.008928570000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0044643,  90.0044643) (180d 0'16.07"W, 90d 0'16.07"N)
Lower Left  (-180.0044643, -90.0044355) (180d 0'16.07"W, 90d 0'15.97"S)
Upper Right ( 180.0044067,  90.0044643) (180d 0'15.86"E, 90d 0'16.07"N)
Lower Right ( 180.0044067, -90.0044355) (180d 0'15.86"E, 90d 0'15.97"S)
Center      (  -0.0000288,   0.0000144) (  0d 0' 0.10"W,  0d 0' 0.05"N)
Band 1 Block=40321x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

What is even stranger is, that the rasters align in QGIS. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: So why do you want to give minY=84 and maxY=16?

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: The reason I have this extent and size, is because it is defined by another raster.

Comment: In your question you have `-te -180 84 180 16`. See usage http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html: `-te xmin ymin xmax ymax`

Comment: So how should the command look like?

Comment: Ok, I see, I should change  84 and 16